# How to run a script in the background then when a condition is met, return it to foreground BASH

Tags: bash

I want to run a script in the background, and when the time comes bring it back from background and call another script that will take in user input from the command-line, when I use this code, it's able to run the script effectively, but when it calls the other script, it only prints out a couple lines and It isn't able to take in user input, just straight up exits out. Been at it for a couple hours, no idea what to do from here.

I call this script with ./runTool.sh &

```
currTime=$(ls -lu | grep test01 | awk '{print $8}')
currHour="${currTime:0:2}"
currMin="${currTime:3:3}"
check=0

while [ true ]
do
    timestamp=$(ls -lu | grep test01 | awk '{print $8}')
    timeHour="${timestamp:0:2}"
    timeMin="${timestamp:3:3}"

    if (( $timeHour > $currHour )) || (( $timeMin > $currMin )) || (($timeHour < $currHour ))
    then
        check=1
        set -m
        fg %1
        ./tool.sh
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: The script can't foreground itself. `fg` has to be run in the shell that spawned the background job.

Comment: would there be a way to run it in the script? I just tested it outside the script and bringing the script back to foreground ran the other script just fine. I am looking to automate this.

Comment: I can't think of any way to do it in the script. Job control is controlled by the original shell, there's no way to force it.

Comment: What should happen if there's some other program running in the foreground when the time is reached?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry I don't understand the question forgive me

Comment: There can only be one foreground program. If the user is running another program, and your background job wants to move into the foreground, how do you expect that conflict to be resolved?